# can I compute an account balance in a more elegant way

Tags: r

I have a series of investment returns for an account that is funded initially and then may have intervening deposits and withdrawals.  I want to create a running balance for the account.  `cumprod` works handily if there are no intermediate cash flows but otherwise I am using a `for()` loop.  This strikes me as the slow way to do it.  Is there a more efficient way?  Thanks.

```
set.seed(100)
return <- c(0,rnorm(5,.05,.02))
cash_flow <- c(100,0,0,-5,0,0)

account <- data.frame(cash_flow,return)
# easy with no intermediate cash flows
# cash flow column is ignored
balance <- account$cash_flow[1] * cumprod(1+account$return)
cbind(account,balance)
#>   cash_flow     return  balance
#> 1       100 0.00000000 100.0000
#> 2         0 0.03995615 103.9956
#> 3         0 0.05263062 109.4690
#> 4        -5 0.04842166 114.7696
#> 5         0 0.06773570 122.5436
#> 6         0 0.05233943 128.9575

# clunky with withdrawal during holding period
balance[1] <- account$cash_flow[1]
for (n in 2:6){
   balance[n] <- (balance[n-1] * (1+account$return[n]) + account$cash_flow[n])
}

cbind(account,balance)
#>   cash_flow     return  balance
#> 1       100 0.00000000 100.0000
#> 2         0 0.03995615 103.9956
#> 3         0 0.05263062 109.4690
#> 4        -5 0.04842166 109.7696
#> 5         0 0.06773570 117.2050
#> 6         0 0.05233943 123.3394
```

EDIT showing speed of the two answers with my original. C routine is 34% faster than original.  `Reduce()` is slower.

```
CB_R <- function(returns,cash_flow,num_rows){
   balance <- cash_flow[1]
   for (n in 2:num_rows){
      balance[n] <- (balance[n-1] * (1+returns[n]) + cash_flow[n])
   }
   return(balance)
}

CB_R2 <- function(returns,cash_flow,num_rows){
   return(
    Reduce(
   f = \(x, i) x * (1 + returns[i]) + cash_flow[i], 
   x = 2:num_rows, 
   init = cash_flow[1],
   acc = TRUE)
   )
}

cppFunction('
NumericVector  CB_C(NumericVector Returns, NumericVector cashFlow,
                              int num_rows) {
  NumericVector balance(num_rows);
  balance[0] = cashFlow[0];
  
  for(int i = 1; i < num_rows; i++){
     balance[i] = (balance[i-1] * (1+Returns[i]) + cashFlow[i]);
  } 
  return balance;  
}')

bench::mark(
   CB_R(account$return,account$cash_flow,nrow(account)),
   CB_R2(account$return,account$cash_flow,nrow(account)),
   CB_C(account$return,account$cash_flow,nrow(account))
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression                             min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                          <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 CB_R(account$return, account$cash_…  5.8µs  6.4µs   144957.   85.87KB     29.0
#> 2 CB_R2(account$return, account$cash… 13.1µs 14.7µs    64339.        0B     25.7
#> 3 CB_C(account$return, account$cash_…  3.7µs  4.2µs   196991.    2.49KB     39.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also not sure if it is faster, but you could write the loop as a Rcpp function.

```r
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
NumericVector  ComputeBalance(NumericVector Returns, NumericVector cashFlow,
                              int num_rows) {
  NumericVector balance(num_rows);
  balance[0] = cashFlow[0];
  
  for(int i = 1; i < num_rows; i++){
     balance[i] = (balance[i-1] * (1+Returns[i]) + cashFlow[i]);
  }
  
  return balance;
  
}')

account$balance <- ComputeBalance(account$return, account$cash_flow, nrow(account))
```

Comment: The C routine is is 34% faster.  See edit above.  I am doing Monte Carlo simulations so this is helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be any faster.  It does eliminate the explicit loop although since one iteration depends on the prior one it ultimately will do the same thing. No packages are used.

```
transform(account, balance = Reduce(
  f = \(x, i) x * (1 + return[i]) + cash_flow[i], 
  x = 2:nrow(account), 
  init = cash_flow[1],
  acc = TRUE))
```